# Replacing left logical shifts with other instructions in MIPS

Tags: mips, bit-shift, logical-operators

So let's say that we have two registers $s0 and $s1. Register $s0 can take values from 0 to 31 and is used to show how many bits register $s1 will be shifted left. How can i do this without using sll or srl. I know that left logical shift by n bits is the same as multiplying with 2^n. This exercise gives a hint that this can be done with 4 instructions only. Both registers are 32-bit.

Comment: 4 instructions, or 4 _lines of code_? I.e., are loops allowed?

Comment: @Michael 4 instructions. It says nothing about loops.

Comment: How many bits does it take to store values between 0 and 31?  How does each bit affect the shift value, and how does that affect the result?  Think this might be related to the four-instruction implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$s1` to itself `$s0` times (each time it will multiply its value by 2 which shifts its bits left once).

The code would look like this:

```
 beqz $s0, end
loop:
  add $s1, $s1, $s1
  subu $s0, $s0, 1
  bnez $s0, loop  
end:
```

The first conditional branch is to ensure no action is taken to `$s1` when `$s0` holds value zero.